# Reactjs Screen not refreshing, always one loop behind when updating

Tags: reactjs, page-refresh

I am updating a record that is being displayed on the screen. Yet once the record is updated in the MySql database, the screen does not reflect the update. I am seeking a way to force the refresh. In the code below, I update the record and reload the array and filter the results. Yet the screen does not get updated. If I click the browsers refresh, the screen displays with the updated data. If I do a second or third update, it always shows the results from the prior update, always one update behind.

I am new to Reactjs so I am hoping this is obvious to someone.

...

```
seqUp(contacttoassetrelationshipid){
    ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationshipById(contacttoassetrelationshipid).then( (res) =>{
        let contacttoassetrelationship = res.data;
        contacttoassetrelationship.contacttoassetRelationshipSequence = contacttoassetrelationship.contacttoassetRelationshipSequence + 1;
        ContactAssetMasterService.updateContactToAssetRelationship(contacttoassetrelationship, contacttoassetrelationshipid);
    });
    ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationship().then((res)
=> {
        this.setState({ contacttoassetrelationship: res.data});
        this.setState({contacttoassetrelationship: this.state.contacttoassetrelationship.filter(contacttoassetrelationship
=> contacttoassetrelationship.assets_assetsid === this.props.match.params.assetsid)});
    }); };
```

...

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. `updateContactToAssetRelationship` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which is an asynchronous operation. Just like
   you did by calling `then` for `getContactToAssetRelationshipById`
   and `getContactToAssetRelationship`, you need to wait until it
   finishes before fetching the updated data. Otherwise, execution
   continues right away (without waiting update call to finish) and
   `getContactToAssetRelationship` fetches out-dated data.
2. setState is an asynchronous operation too. Plus, multiple calls of setState merged into one batch call. In the following case, for example, count will be updated only once:

- 

```
// assume this.state.count === 0
this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
// count will be 1
```

Final code (removed/renamed variables just for brievity):

```
seqUp(contacttoassetrelationshipid){
        ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationshipById(contacttoassetrelationshipid).then((res) =>{
            res.data.contacttoassetRelationshipSequence++;
            ContactAssetMasterService.updateContactToAssetRelationship(res.data, contacttoassetrelationshipid).then(() => {
                ContactAssetMasterService.getContactToAssetRelationship().then((res1) => {
                    this.setState({contacttoassetrelationship: res1.data.filter(c => c.assets_assetsid === this.props.match.params.assetsid)});
                });
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: No change, same results

Comment: Wow..works great !
Can you explain where my code did not work and why your modification works?
I appreciate your time and help. Beers on me !

Comment: So by nesting the functions inside of each other they are forced to wait for the prior one to complete so they can received the updated results? right?

Comment: @HighwayRob You'd better see the link in my answer to understand how promises work. "A pending promise can either be fulfilled with a value or rejected with a reason (error). When either of these options happens, the associated handlers queued up by a promise's `then` method are called."